# Accessing Class Object Inside Nested Functions in Python

Tags: python, class, global

In my dashboard I do different analyses on different datasets from different projects.
Now I want to make the program an the use should be able to choose the dataset/project and the analysis to be displayed.
I use the following program structure:

```
# config.py
'''This module defines the basic parameters for each project. In real life this would be datapaths, etc.'''

class Config():

    def __init__(self, selection):
        self.select_project(selection)

    def select_project(self, selection):

        if selection == "1":
            self.x = 3
            self.y = 4

        elif selection == "2":
            self.x = 5
            self.y = 6
```

---

```
#analysis1.py
''' this module displays analysis 1'''

def write():
    sum = cfg_object.x + cfg_object.y
    print(sum)
```

---

```
#analysis2.py
''' this module displays analysis 1'''

def write():
    product = cfg_object.x * cfg_object.y
    print(product)
```

---

```
# navigation.py
'''This modules enables the user to choose the type of analysis'''

import config as cfg
import analysis1
import analysis2


def write(selection):
    cfg_object = cfg.Config(selection)
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(cfg_object.x)
    print(cfg_object.y)
    analysis_selection = input("Do you want Analysis 1 or 2?")
    print(analysis_selection)
    
    if analysis_selection == "1":
        analysis1.write()
    elif analysis_selection == "2":
        analysis2.write()
```

---

```
# main.py
'''This main module starts with choosing the project'''

import navigation
selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
navigation.write(selection)
```

If I run this program, the `analysis1.py` and `analysis2.py` modules cannot access `cfg_object.x` defined in the `write` function of the `navigation.py` module.
How can I make these variables also accessible in other functions?
Do I have to define them as globals or is there a more elegant approach?

The error message is the following:

```
Project 1 or 2?1
This is project 1
3
4
Do you want Analysis 1 or 2?2
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    navigation.write(selection)
  File "navigation.py", line 16, in write
    analysis2.write()
  File "analysis2.py", line 2, in write
    product = cfg_object.x * cfg_object.y
NameError: name 'cfg_object' is not defined
```

Comment: `cfg_object` is not defined in the function's scope, you need to pass it there.

Comment: ah, this was simple! just calling the analysis with `analysis1.write(cfg_object)` solves the problem... thanks for the quick the response!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Uriya Harpness, the problem was easy to solve.
`cfg_object` has to be passed to the other functions.

the working code looks then like this:

```
# config.py
'''This module defines the basic parameters for each project. In real life this would be datapaths, etc.'''

class Config():

    def __init__(self, selection):
        self.select_project(selection)

    def select_project(self, selection):

        if selection == "1":
            self.x = 3
            self.y = 4

        elif selection == "2":
            self.x = 5
            self.y = 6
```

---

```
#analysis1.py
''' this module displays analysis 1'''

def write(cfg_object):
    sum = cfg_object.x + cfg_object.y
    print(sum)
```

---

```
#analysis2.py
''' this module displays analysis 1'''

def write(cfg_object):
    product = cfg_object.x * cfg_object.y
    print(product)
```

---

```
# navigation.py
'''This modules enables the user to choose the type of analysis'''

import config as cfg
import analysis1
import analysis2


def write(selection):
    cfg_object = cfg.Config(selection)
    print(f'This is project {selection}')
    print(cfg_object.x)
    print(cfg_object.y)
    analysis_selection = input("Do you want Analysis 1 or 2?")
    print(analysis_selection)
    
    if analysis_selection == "1":
        analysis1.write(cfg_object)
    elif analysis_selection == "2":
        analysis2.write(cfg_object)
```

---

```
# main.py
'''This main module starts with choosing the project'''

import navigation
selection = input("Project 1 or 2?")
navigation.write(selection)
```